# How do I create an SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a very fundamental and basic SQL question.  Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express, how do I create my first Server?  For that matter, how would I create it using any other required software tool?

I took a look at Sql Server Configuration Manager and I saw SQLEPRESS running as a SQL Server.  But when I added that in to the start up widow for MSSM Studio Express, as the server name, it threw an error saying it cannot be found or does not exist.  It seems that this is not the right kind of server.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes try that. Or drop down the server names and press <borwse> and see if you can see it in there.

Comment: In addition to tall this, I am trying to use entity framework in visual studio.  Although .\SQLEXPRESS did not work in the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express (I think I need to relaunch it in Admin mode or something), using .\SQLEXPRESS did work as the name of the server in the entity framework setting.

Comment: Trying .\SQLEXPRESS in SQL Server Management Studio Express throws an error that says that "This version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express can only be used to connect to SQL Server 2005 servers".  So this is the problem, I think.

Comment: OK so you have an old version of SSMS. Download the correct or later version. You can download express tools for free. Remember you only really need to download and install the _tools_ as you already have a server install. If you can't find a tools-only install just download the lot and install tools in the install wizard.

Answer (score 1):

To connect to the local instance of SQLEXPRESS, you will need `localhost` as the server name.

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms186312.aspx) is a fairly comprehensive guide on how to create a database once you have connected. All the steps won't apply to using SQL Express, but the gist of it is there.

1. In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of the SQL Server Database
   Engine and then expand that instance.
2. Right-click Databases, and then
   click New Database. In New Database, enter a database name.
3. To create
   the database by accepting all default values, click OK; otherwise,
   continue with the following optional steps.

Comment: localhost did not work.  The error is the same.  One clue might be in the fact that it says that I need to make sure that SQL Server is configured to allow for remote connections.  I will add this in the original post.

Comment: Sqlexpress is a named instance thus .\sqlexpress is advised

Answer (score 0):

Based on this comment:

> > Trying .\SQLEXPRESS in SQL Server Management Studio Express throws an error that says that "This version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express can only be used to connect to SQL Server 2005 servers". So this is the problem, I think.

`.\SQLEXPRESS` is the correct server name, but you have the wrong version of client tools (SQL Server Management Studio). To find out the version of SQL you are connecting to, there are a number of suggestions here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1140/how-to-tell-what-sql-server-version-you-are-running/

But since you can't connect yet the easiest thing to do is go searching for `sqlserver.exe`, right click, properties, version. If you have multiple version you need take note of the folder that it's in and check the SQLExpress one. You can also check in services.

Once you've worked out the version, download and install just the management tools for that version.